# Full Calendar Dropping Event Objects After Data Transform

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am having a strange issue with full calendar. I am trying to create a mouseover for different types of events and have had some issues with attributes of an event object disappearing between the "eventDataTransform" and "eventMouseover" functions

This is for a web application that will be loading data from an API to populate full calendar. I am able to get all of the object's attributes when I do not perform a transformation on the event. I am inspecting the object and show that it is present when the object is transformed and not so when it is moused over.

```
calendar = $("#k_calendar").fullCalendar({
  isRTL: KUtil.isRTL(),
  header: {
    left: "prev,next today",
    center: "title",
    right: "month"
  },
  editable: false,
  eventLimit: false,
  navLinks: true,
  weekends: true,
  eventSources: [
    // Loaded from a previous source
    data,
    "{% url 'pentesting-api:pentest-events' %}"
  ],
  displayEventTime: false,
  // Where the error is
  eventDataTransform: function (eventData) {
    if (eventData.hasOwnProperty('vendor')) {
      eventData.end = moment(eventData.end).add(1, 'days').format();
      eventData.title = eventData.full_name;
      eventData.backgroundColor = statusColors[eventData.status];
      eventData.allDay = true;
      return eventData;

    }
    else {
      eventData.title = eventData.event_name;
      eventData.backgroundColor = eventColors[eventData.event_type];
      // all attributes are on the object here
      console.log(eventData);
      return eventData;
    }
    // Using the below commented out code works but doesn't distinguish between events 
    // eventData.end = moment(eventData.end).add(1, 'days').format();
    //   eventData.title = eventData.full_name;
    //   eventData.backgroundColor = statusColors[eventData.status];
    //   return eventData;
  },
  eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    closePopovers();
    // console.log(event);
    if (event.hasOwnProperty('event_type')) {
      console.log('this mouse over');
      // object dropped the 'end' attribute
      console.log(event);
      let start_base, end_base, start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time;
      start_base = event.start.format().split('T');
      start_date = start_base[0];
      start_time = start_base[1].split('-')[0].split(':')[0] + ':' + start_base[1].split('-')[0].split(':')[1];
      end_base = event.end.format().split('T');
      end_date = end_base[0];
      end_time = end_base[1].split('-')[0].split(':')[0] + ':' + end_base[1].split('-')[0].split(':')[1];
      popoverElement = $(jsEvent.target);
      $(jsEvent.target).popover({
        title: event.event_name,
        content: function () {
          let content;
          content = 'Event Type: ' + event.event_type +
            '<br>Start: ' + start_date + ' ' + start_time +
            '<br>End: ' + end_date + ' ' + end_time +
            '<br>Resource: ' + event.resource;
          return content
        },
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true
      }).popover('show')
    }
    else {
      var end = event.end.subtract(1, 'days').format().split('T')[0];
      popoverElement = $(jsEvent.target);
      $(jsEvent.target).popover({
        title: event.title,
        content: function () {
          var content;
          content = 'Pentest ID: ' + event.id +
            '<br>Pentest Status:' + event.status +
            '<br>Start Date: ' + event.start.format() +
            '<br>End Date: ' + end +
            '<br>Resources: ' + event.tester +
            '<br>Duration: ' + event.duration;
          return content
        },
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true
      }).popover('show')
    }
  },
  eventMouseout: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
    $(jsEvent.target).popover('hide')
  }
})});
```

I am expecting the input from the mouseover includes the 'end' object attribute, however, it is not present. When doing the if, else eventDataTransformation, all of the object attributes are there including the 'end' attribute. When the data event is logged in the eventMouseover function, every attribute is there except for 'end'.

Event data transform object (what I want)

```
{
  "id": 11,
  "resource": "1",
  "event_name": "Test Event",
  "start": "2019-03-29T08:52:44.330075-07:00",
  "end": "2019-03-29T08:52:44.330173-07:00",
  "event_type": "Demo",
  "pentest_id": null,
  "title": "Test Event",
  "backgroundColor": "#ADD8E6"
}
```

Object being passed to the eventMouseover function (same object but missing the 'end' attribute)

```
id: "_fc12"
allDay: false
backgroundColor: "#ADD8E6"
className: Array []
end: null
event_name: "Test Event"
event_type: "Demo"
id: 11
pentest_id: null
resource: "1"
source: Object { calendar: {…}, uid: "4", url: "/api/pentesting/events/", … }
start: Object { _isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2019-03-29T08:52:44.330075-07:00", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ", … }
title: "Test Event"
<prototype>: Object { … }
pentesting:1781:23
```

Comment: Shouldn't be tagged `django`

Comment: Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the specifications (documented well in this bug report - https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3688), the end date MUST be different than the start date (or the end date will be 'null'!)

I would also be careful on making the end date BEFORE the start - in your eventMouseover you are subtracting a day - you should probably do a quick check to make sure the end is > (not = as you will have the 'null' issue...) the start.  I didn't find anything on having the end before the start, but I'm pretty sure fullCalendar would 'dismiss' it (likely with a null as well since end is optional).

Comment: The problem was having the start and end date being basically the same. I was able to create new events that had different start and end dates which fixed the issue. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Glad that worked out for you.  For future reference, you sometimes may want the 'null' - for all day events, etc. - just something to keep in your 'bag-o-tricks' which will grow (and grow!) as you do more programming.  Happy Coding!